# App Cache in Safari 14. Why does this no longer work?

Tags: safari, html5-appcache

I have an aging PWA that uses App Cache for an offline mode. Today, when I browse with safari 14, my App Cache manifest never loads. In the Network tab of web inspector, it just sits there with the spinner spinning forever. If I request the url directly in a new tab, it loads no problem. CanIUse says safari still supports App Cache, and this was working at one time. An old Iphone 5s with Safari 10.3.3 still works fine. Does anyone have any tips?

This is my manifest declaration...

```
<html manifest="static.manifest">
```

Comment: Also Firefox has now removed appcache, the same issue here: *quota exceeded* error and spinning forever Did You solved this issue in some way? Do You have some knowledge to share about this topic? I still need to maintain appcache for my legacy users, sob.

Comment: Appcache is working for safari still, but has disappeared from Chrome and Firefox. Google [have a polyfill](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/sw-appcache-behavior) that implements appcache with service worker. At present, we're sniffing for safari. If we don't find it, we serve the service worker polyfill.